# NASM Assembler question marks in console

Tags: assembly, x86-64, nasm

I have a problem with my NASM program. At the moment I'm trying to connect two strings. 
That works pretty well, but when I'm write in line 15: `mov rsi, msg2` instead of `mov rsi, 30h` the program prints weird output and I don't know why.

The first print on console window is with `mov rsi, msg2` and the second with `mov rsi, 30h`.

Console output:

```
simon@simon:~/Projekte/NASM$ bash ./run.sh
Ich verbinde mich mit �`

simon@simon:~/Projekte/NASM$ bash ./run.sh
Ich verbinde mich mit 0
```

Code:

```
%include 'functions.asm'

SECTION .data
msg1    db      'Ich verbinde mich mit ', 0h;23
msg2    db      '0';2

SECTION .bss
name:   RESB  255

SECTION .text
global  _start

_start:
  mov     rax, msg1
  mov     rsi, 30h ;so it will work and so   mov     rsi, msg2 not!

  push    rax
  call    strlen
  mov     rdi, rax;rdi ist jetzt die Länge
  pop     rax
  mov     [rax + rdi], rsi;Ursprungsstring + Länge

  call    print
  call    exit
```

functions.asm

```
strlen:
  push    rbx;Auf den Stack werfen
  mov     rbx, rax

nextchar:
  cmp     byte [rax], 0
  jz      finished
  inc     rax
  jmp     nextchar

finished:
  sub     rax, rbx
  pop     rbx;Aus dem Stack ziehen
  ret

exit:
  push    rax
  push    rbx
  mov     rax, 1;op code 1
  mov     rbx, 0;0 errors
  int     80h
  pop     rax
  pop     rbx
  ret

printstrlen:;rbx repräsentiert Nachricht, rax die Länge.
  push    rcx
  push    rdx
  push    rax
  push    rbx
  mov     rcx, rbx
  mov     rdx, rax
  mov     rax, 4
  mov     rbx, 1
  int     80h
  pop     rcx
  pop     rdx
  pop     rax
  pop     rbx
  ret

print:
  push    rbx
  mov     rbx, rax
  call    strlen
  call    printstrlen
  pop     rbx
  ret
```

Thanks you for help.

Best regards

Comment: Please don't post code as image. Also show all the code, including the `print` and the `strlen`. As always, learn to use a debugger.

Comment: But what is the reason behind putting 30h there?

Comment: I'm testing at the moment and 30h is the ASCII Code for the number zero. In msg2    db      '0';2 is the number zero as well, but that's only work when I'm write:
mov rsi, 30h

and not when I'm writing 
mov rsi, msg2

Comment: `print` printed what was actually there: bytes of the pointer.

Comment: Run your program under `strace` to see a hexdump of the binary data you pass to `write`

Comment: In general, `int 80h` is wrong for a 64-bit program, and you should use the `syscall` interface instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
mov rsi, msg2
```

loads the *address* of msg2 into rsi. You want to load the value. Use

```
movzx rsi, byte [msg2]
```

Comment: There are other problems with this code. For example, it overwrites the null byte that marks the end of msg1. And it also overwrites the next 7 bytes past the end of msg1. You should define msg1 with extra space after it. You may want to change `mov [rax+rdi], rsi` to `mov [rax+rdi], sil` so it only adds a single character to the string. Sil is the low byte of rsi. And make sure to put a null byte at the end of msg1 after you change it.